# Should I wrap class instances with observable properties in another observable on the viewModel?

Tags: knockout.js

I have a constructable object with observable properties

```
function Item() { this.prop = ko.observable() }
```

My view model creates an instance of Item

```
var instance = ko.observable(new Item())
```

Should I not wrap the instance in an observable on the ViewModel?  If I don't wrap "item" in an observable then the component doesn't work at all.

```
var instance = new Item()
```

I pass that instance into a component as a param.

```
<component params="item: item"></component>
```

I can't figure out how to bind to the instance's observable properties from the component template.  The disabled class is not changing when the badge.disabled observable changes.

```
template: '<img class="ui image" src="http://fakeimg.pl/300/" data-bind="css: { disabled: item().disabled }" >'
```

This is the full example.

https://gist.github.com/guyjacks/2b4c18fe7f4f7bf9b34059e9019d0918

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to modify some of your model code

```
 ko.components.register('badge-button', {
            viewModel: function(params) {
                var self = this;

                 self.badge = params.badge();
                 self.open = function() {

                    self.badge.toggleHas();
                    self.badge.toggleActive();
                }
            },

            template: 
                '<img class="ui image" src="http://fakeimg.pl/300/" data-bind="click: open, css: { disabled: badge.disabled }" >'
        });
```

Working Example : http://jsfiddle.net/GSvnh/5137/

Comment: That does work, but it doesn't work when I create the badge within the ajax callback.  knockout-min.js:16 Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding "css: function (){return { disabled:badge.disabled} }"
Message: Cannot read property 'disabled' of undefined

Comment: Make sure you get data in your Ajax's success . or if it does not go to success call back  at all where you create new instance, then it would be `undefined` for the component

Comment: Logging the instance shows that its correctly created in the callback.

Comment: Most probably kockout loads the component before your new instance is created inside Ajax success.

Comment: If that's the case, how do you create components that rely on remote data?